# PaperJS growth rectangle (scale)

Tags: javascript, html, animation, paperjs

I've a circle and a rectangle object in paperjs. Now i want to make an animation. In that animation the circle goes up and the rectangle has to growth after the circle (at bottom of the circle). I've an example here (not working in that way i want it to)

[example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/bZPPT4MwFMf/lYbLICJDku2wxZOJJw9GLxrx0HXP0YAtKRU2l/3vvpZ2wCYn+t6338/7AcdA0G8IVsFrCZoVQRwwuTXnlirCuGIVPFNdkHsioCPmNXmw0dCeJRc6XKQxWaRRTLJFtM7FcCtptJIlPMhKKnSYbSrKyhlKcmHsFTBNxe6a8OIT4TEXBJ/acFbkI0NSln7GfbThv4DBJQaXQ3BArjwxF6foTN1gZKfkj9g+0QMox7XvHscKXm0VCDQfmokn5XpcLRuuuURpy6FLGAgNasJD92cnQlaWpjYzGpIUjwp3gMmvH8GMLoQWfSKsJtfGokWydJV6r9uRgy8iORhv/W+G3Nx7nzluywpxDJ2ZdThpLdmY4TRJx7fY9XRLI8P/C7jQmzGcbMO+N3KGOv8C+K7QMYEKviO3ANN0w2gFb9i01c1NelLZ+kL6jtLea6LtQ2tCBnmtoMUxus3XtAaV9F/y+OI+Hp8O/UKNhQ1bZNjXGPf8QeEAyd4M/arwebaeyg6XMteG142w9fAludvnAeOvu1FAS/uvNMHqI7jLgs/THw==)

the code:

```
var circlePath = new Path.Circle(new Point(50, 50), 25);
circlePath.strokeColor = 'black';

var rectanglePath = new Path.Rectangle({
    point: [20, 20],
    size: [60, 60],
    strokeColor: 'black'
});

var backgroundLayer = new Layer({
    children: [circlePath,rectanglePath],
    position: view.center
});

var newPosition = 200;

circlePath.onFrame = function(event){
    var vector = newPosition-circlePath.position.y;
    circlePath.position.y += vector / 50;
    growRect(rectanglePath.bounds.width, rectanglePath.position.y-circlePath.position.y, rectanglePath);
};

function growRect(width, height, elem){
    var scaleX = width/elem.bounds.width;
    var scaleY = height/elem.bounds.height;  
    var prevPos = new paper.Point(elem.bounds.x,elem.bounds.y);

    elem.scale(scaleX,scaleY);

    prevPos.x += elem.bounds.width/2;
    prevPos.y += elem.bounds.height/2;

    elem.position = prevPos;
};
```

maybe someone could help me out!

Comment: When you say the rectangle has to grow up, do you mean it grows but stays the same distance from the circle? It's not clear how you want this to behave.

Comment: You don't start with the rectangle at the bottom of the circle. That's unclear for me.

Answer (score 1):

The `scale` function can have the center point as a third parameter. If you use the bottom of the rectangle for the scale center, it may behave as you want it to. Also, the code will be slightly shorter. You can try it [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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)

```
var circlePath = new Path.Circle(new Point(50, 50), 25);
circlePath.strokeColor = 'black';

var rectanglePath = new Path.Rectangle({
    point: [20, 20],
    size: [60, 60],
    strokeColor: 'black'
});

var backgroundLayer = new Layer({
    children: [circlePath,rectanglePath],
    position: view.center
});

var newPosition = 200;

circlePath.onFrame = function(event){
    var vector = newPosition-circlePath.position.y;
    circlePath.position.y += vector / 50;
    growRect(rectanglePath.bounds.width, rectanglePath.position.y-circlePath.position.y, rectanglePath);
};

function growRect(width, height, elem){
    var scaleX = width/elem.bounds.width;
    var scaleY = height/elem.bounds.height;  
    elem.scale(scaleX,scaleY, new paper.Point(elem.bounds.x,elem.bounds.bottom));
```